# Google API Redirect URI not working properly

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I'm new to Google API and am having trouble getting the Analytics API to work. So far I've set up the Developer Console, created a project, and generated the relevant credentials. My registered email ID is `myname@mycompany.com`, and the redirect URI is set to `http://www.mycompany.com/oauth2callback` by default. The JavaScript Origins is set to `http://www.mycompany.com`.

When I run the project from localhost, I'm able to initiate the OAuth procedure. But when I hit the "allow" button, I'm sent to `http://www.mycompany.com`and nothing happens. What could I be doing wrong? Do I need to be running this script from the mycompany.com doamin for it to work? Lastly, how can I run it from localhost?

```
<?php
include_once "google_api/autoload.php";

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Hello Analytics API Example");

$client->setClientId('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
$client->setClientSecret('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
//$client->setRedirectUri('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
$client->setRedirectUri('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
$client->setDeveloperKey('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'));

// Magic. Returns objects from the Analytics Service instead of associative arrays.
//print_r($client);
//$client->setUseObjects(true);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) 
{
    $client->authenticate();
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if (!$client->getAccessToken()) 
{
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
} 
else 
{
    // Create analytics service object. See next step below.
    $analytics = new apiAnalyticsService($client);
    runMainDemo($analytics);
}

function runMainDemo(&$analytics) {
    try {

        // Step 2. Get the user's first view (profile) ID.
        $profileId = getFirstProfileId($analytics);

        if (isset($profileId)) {

            // Step 3. Query the Core Reporting API.
            $results = getResults($analytics, $profileId);

            // Step 4. Output the results.
            printResults($results);
        }

    } catch (apiServiceException $e) {
        // Error from the API.
        print 'There was an API error : ' . $e->getCode() . ' : ' . $e->getMessage();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print 'There wan a general error : ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

function getFirstprofileId(&$analytics) {
    $accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();

    if (count($accounts->getItems()) > 0) {
        $items = $accounts->getItems();
        $firstAccountId = $items[0]->getId();

        $webproperties = $analytics->management_webproperties
        ->listManagementWebproperties($firstAccountId);

        if (count($webproperties->getItems()) > 0) {
            $items = $webproperties->getItems();
            $firstWebpropertyId = $items[0]->getId();

            $profiles = $analytics->management_profiles
            ->listManagementProfiles($firstAccountId, $firstWebpropertyId);

            if (count($profiles->getItems()) > 0) {
                $items = $profiles->getItems();
                return $items[0]->getId();

            } else {
                throw new Exception('No views (profiles) found for this user.');
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception('No webproperties found for this user.');
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception('No accounts found for this user.');
    }
}

function getResults(&$analytics, $profileId) {
    return $analytics->data_ga->get(
            'ga:' . $profileId,
            '2012-03-03',
            '2012-03-03',
            'ga:sessions');
}

function printResults(&$results) {
    if (count($results->getRows()) > 0) {
        $profileName = $results->getProfileInfo()->getProfileName();
        $rows = $results->getRows();
        $sessions = $rows[0][0];

        print "<p>First view (profile) found: $profileName</p>";
        print "<p>Total sessions: $sessions</p>";

    } else {
    print '<p>No results found.</p>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to let others see there Google Analytics data or are you trying to give others access to your Google analytics Data?  You really need to add some code before we can help you.

Comment: @DalmTo I want to make an app that requests a user's permission and pulls read-only data from their Analytics. For now I'm testing it through my own account, so the developer as well as user account is `myname@mycompany.com`. Code added, although it's only the official tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to request there data automated you will need to store the refreshtoken.  If you only want them to be able to access there data when they are on your site then this should get you started.

The latest Google PHP client lib can be found here. [Github](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)

```
<?php         
require_once 'Google/Client.php';     
require_once 'Google/Service/Analytics.php';       
session_start();      
$client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
    $client->setDeveloperKey("{devkey}");  
    $client->setClientId('{clientid}.apps.googleusercontent.com');
    $client->setClientSecret('{clientsecret}');
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://www.daimto.com/Tutorials/PHP/Oauth2.php');
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'));

    //For loging out.
    if ($_GET['logout'] == "1") {
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
       }   

    // Step 2: The user accepted your access now you need to exchange it.
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {

        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);  
        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }

    // Step 1:  The user has not authenticated we give them a link to login    
    if (!$client->getAccessToken() && !isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
        }        

    // Step 3: We have access we can now create our service
    if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        print "<a class='logout' href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?logout=1'>LogOut</a><br>";
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
        $service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);    

        // request user accounts
        $accounts = $service->management_accountSummaries->listManagementAccountSummaries();

       foreach ($accounts->getItems() as $item) {
        echo "Account: ",$item['name'], "  " , $item['id'], "<br /> \n";        
        foreach($item->getWebProperties() as $wp) {
            echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;WebProperty: ' ,$wp['name'], "  " , $wp['id'], "<br /> \n";    

            $views = $wp->getProfiles();
            if (!is_null($views)) {
                foreach($wp->getProfiles() as $view) {
                //  echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;View: ' ,$view['name'], "  " , $view['id'], "<br /> \n";    
                }
            }
        }
    } // closes account summaries

    }
 print "<br><br><br>";
 print "Access from google: " . $_SESSION['token']; 
?>
```

Code ripped from the tutorial [Google Analytics Oauth2 with php](http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-php/).

**Update**: After looking at your code I think part of your problem may be that you aren't linking the redirectURi to a page.  It cant just be a directory you must give it the php page that it should redirect to.

Comment: @DalmTo I think that is the case. Sorry for my ignorance, but what is the redirectURI PHP script supposed to do? I mean the login credentials are stored in the source script . . . Do I need to retrieve it from the session?

Comment: Redirect URI basically tells the Authentication server where to return the authentication to.   The one file should be able to Handel it all check step 2.

Comment: @DalmTo Thanks! I've accepted the answer for now. Will try it soon. :)